# Simplified way to get assembly description in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, .net-4.0, lambda

I was reading through a .NET 2.0 book and came across this sample code which gets the applications assembly description :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    object[] attributes = 
        assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        AssemblyDescriptionAttribute descriptionAttribute =
            (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attributes[0];
        Console.WriteLine(descriptionAttribute.Description);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It's quite a lot of code to simply get the assembly description and I would like to know if there's a simpler way of doing this in .NET 3.5+ using LINQ or lambda expressions?

Comment: I think this code is good enough

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There isn't, really. You can make it a bit 'more fluent' like this:

```
 var descriptionAttribute = assembly
         .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
         .OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>()
         .FirstOrDefault();

 if (descriptionAttribute != null) 
     Console.WriteLine(descriptionAttribute.Description);
```

[EDIT changed Assembly to ICustomAttributeProvider, cf. answer by Simon Svensson)

And if you need this kind of code a lot, make an extension method on ICustomAttributeProvider:

```
 public static T GetAttribute<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider assembly, bool inherit = false) 
 where T : Attribute 
 {
     return assembly
         .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit)
         .OfType<T>()
         .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Since .Net 4.5, as Yuriy explained, an extension method is available in the framework:

```
var descriptionAttribute = 
    assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>();
```

Comment: `assembly` in `var descriptionAttribute = assembly` came from the air...

Comment: Note that this `GetAttribute` might not work for all assembly attributes. For example, to get the `AssemblyVersionAttribute`, you can use `assembly.GetName().Version` instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
var attribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
if (attribute != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(attribute.Description);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use an extension method for [ICustomAttributeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.icustomattributeprovider.getcustomattributes.aspx) to provide a strongly typed `GetCustomAttributes` which returns a strongly typed enumerable. The only linq usage would be the call to `FirstOrDefault` and `OfType`

```
public static void Main() {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var descriptionAttribute = assembly
        .GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>(inherit: false)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (descriptionAttribute != null) {
        Console.WriteLine(descriptionAttribute.Description);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static IEnumerable<T> GetCustomAttributes<T>(this ICustomAttributeProvider provider, bool inherit) where T : Attribute {
    return provider.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit).OfType<T>();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need LINQ or lambda expressions in this case.

Since .NET 4.5 you can enjoy [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.5#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttribute__1_System_Reflection_Assembly_) to reflect attribute:

```
var descriptionAttribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>();

if (descriptionAttribute != null)
    Console.WriteLine(descriptionAttribute.Description);
```

Answer (score 3):

Following @ab-kolan answer, it could be simpler:

```
    var description = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
            .OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault()?
            .Description ?? "";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in the current executing process (versus assembly as per the original post), then it's a simple one liner..

```
Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileVersionInfo.Comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

While this code is already relatively concise, you *could* leverage a little bit of LINQ to clean it up a touch.

```
AssemblyDescriptionAttribute attribute = assembly
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
    .OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>()
    .SingleOrDefault();

if(attribute != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(attribute.Description);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static string GetDescription(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
            .Select(a => a as AssemblyDescriptionAttribute).FirstOrDefault();

        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        return attribute.Description;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetDescription());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go -- it condenses easily to two lines of code -- and if that's too big, you can dump it into an extension method:

```
public static string GetAssemblyDescription(this Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false)
        .OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()?.Description;
}
```

Then you just use the extension method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetAssemblyDescription());
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're referring to the Description in the Assembly Information:
[image: Project's Assembly Information Window]

[right click on a project -> Application -> Assembly Information]

I would recommend using the [AssemblyInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo?view=netframework-4.8) Class,
you can see an example [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/353819/Get-all-Assembly-Information):

when I've used it, I had a `Type type` in hand by using reflection and i did that:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

AssemblyInfo info = new AssemblyInfo(type.Assembly);
string description = info.Description;
```

Comment: You didn't answer a question in my opionion. Question is no how to check under Visual Studio a description, but how to get description in the code. If answer can be found under one of your links, then put example code here.

Comment: I didn't minus your answer, so at least one person has same feeling like I. Main place in your answer is about where description is. SO answer guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer tells "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." - that's why I put comment.